# Kotlin 1.5 builds significantly slower than 1.4

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Upgrading from Kotlin 1.4.32 to 1.5.x i noticed a significantly higher build time, especially on re-builds without code changes it takes about **1 minute** longer. My project is quite large, a *installDebug*-Build without code changes takes 46s (1.4) or 1m 53s (1.5) averaged.
Most of this time (~50-55 seconds) gradle spents on the task "configuring projects".

Has anyone else experienced such increase in build times? Or anyone maybe even has a solution or at least a hint on what is causing that massive increase?
I am using Android-Gradle-Plugin 7 and Gradle 7.1 (older versions did not solve the problem).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try using [Gradle's configuration cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html) if that's what takes time for you.

The Kotlin gradle plugin started being [compatible with configuration cache in 1.5](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13490) so maybe the changes made there slowed down the regular un-cached configuration phase (but that's really just a wild guess). In any case, configuration cache should definitely give you a boost in this phase.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, sadly my dependencies seem to be not compatible yet. But I will take note for the future.